# VisualForce Controller SOQL query prematurely limited

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I have a visual force page visual force page that references my controlling class 'ESWebCaseController.cls'.

The visual force page has a field called 'Company' that runs on an SF site and is accessible by anyone when the form is submitted is used in a SOQL query like:

```
List account_list = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name =:company];
```

This query returns 0 results when company = Acme, however this same query returns 1 result when done using the Eclipse IDE SF Schema. There is defnately a company named Acme in my org.

When I remove the WHERE clause in the query, 10 Accounts are returnted, even if I set LIMIT 100, only 10 accounts are returned. These 10 accounts seem to have one thing in common and that is that they reference the same parent account and/or have a specific field ID that references the parent account.

I want to know if there is anything that would cause the above query in my controlling class to be limited outside of the Query itself.

Below are the debug logs for the Query:

```
20:28:32.158 (158986000)|POP_TRACE_FLAGS|[163]|01p500000009goT|ESWebCaseController|APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,FINEST;CALLOUT,FINEST;DB,FINEST;SYSTEM,FINEST;VALIDATION,FINEST;VISUALFORCE,FINEST;WORKFLOW,FINEST
20:28:32.159 (159879000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[163]|Aggregations:0|select Name from Account where Name = :tmpVar1
20:28:32.159 (159893000)|LIMIT_USAGE|[163]|SOQL|1|100
20:28:32.159 (159898000)|LIMIT_USAGE|[163]|AGGS|0|300
20:28:32.177 (177286000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[163]|Rows:0
20:28:32.177 (177308000)|LIMIT_USAGE|[163]|SOQL_ROWS|0|50000
20:28:32.177 (177324000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[163]|Bytes:4
20:28:32.177 (177337000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[163]|Bytes:0
20:28:32.177 (177411000)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[163]|Bytes:4
20:28:32.177 (177441000)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[163]|account_list|LIST<Account>|true|false
20:28:32.177 (177488000)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[163]|account_list|{"serId":1,"value":[]}|0x14cace14
20:28:32.177 (177504000)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[165]
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the Controller class With Sharing (default) or Without Sharing, the visibility is likely to do with ownership and sharing. Try declaring the class as without sharing if you intend overriding the sharing for display.

Comment: And also check the sharing rules for the Account and make sure they're not private. Are you using the same user for executing this code and for the schema too?

Comment: I made sure the Account was Read access to the user/class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VisualForce Sites permissions are edited from the site configuration page.  There is a button titled "Public Access Settings".  You'll recognize this screen as the profile edit page.  The controls are limited however and don't allow the ability to grant modify all/view all on some standard objects, although custom objects do have this ability.  To get around this you can declare your class as "without sharing".  This makes your class run in system mode, and ignore the sharing rules and data security.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm

**Be extra careful using without sharing, especially on a Sites page.  This class will have the ability to completely expose your data publicly if you make a design mistake.**  I post a large warning in the comment header at the top of any of my without sharing classes used on Sites pages.

One exception I've run across when using without sharing, if you're using a standardController with an extension class, the controller is reading in sharing mode no matter what you do.  If you need to access protected data in the extension, you'll need to query it inside the extension that has without sharing enabled.

Comment: it was a combination of the Public Access Settings and specific permissions on my 'Site Guest User'. I had looked at that before posting, but sometimes it takes that extra look. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty workaround would be to change the OWD of account to public read only. However its not recommended unless you bussiness model supports it. The best possible solution is what **techtrekker** suggested. Ensure that the controller of your visualforce page is without sharing, this will ensure that the users can access data in system context.